# how to configure poll scm everyday midnight 1 am in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

i want to configure poll scm every day midnight 1 am and except saturday and sunday in jenkins. is there any another way to do  nightly builds

After build success how to send build report to the team.

how to integrate unit test cases in to jenkins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the cron schedule try this:
`0 0 * * 1-5`
The last 1-5 means only on days 1 to 5. Day 0 is Sunday, Day 1 is Monday, and so on.

For the email, check mark **E-mail Notification** in the post-build actions, and specify which email addresses to include in the notification. For more advanced email options, consider downloading and investigating https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

For your last question, you didn't provide any information to help us answer it. Unit test on what language? Do you already have unit test written in SVN? What kind of build are you doing? Maven unit tests would be executed directly by Maven, where as PHP unit test cases would require something else. There is not enough information to answer this.